# Run a setup.py from a directory different from the package's directory

Tags: python, setup.py

I want to run the setup.py of a Distutils-packaged package and my current directory is not the package's directory so I get this  error:

```
error in 'egg_base' option: 'src' does not exist or is not a directory
```

Comment: Why do you need to not be in that directory?

Comment: Why don't you change directory to there?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.

I just didn't notice these lines in setup.py:

```py
package_dir={"": "src"},
packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="src"),
```

Which basically means that the source code should be inside the src file.
So I **just put all the source code into a src file** and it fixed the issue.

The project's structure should be

```
> src
---- code.py
setup.py
```